# Added a Database Including Images... Can't seem to call the Image from the Database on an Activity

Tags: java, android, database, image

Had an issue yesterday with images sizes and that was resolved timely after some advice from someone here. This issue poses more of an issue to me...

Basically I've developed my Application further and now have a button called "ChordDB" when I click on this button I want it to load my 'ChordImages.java' activity and display the 'Name' and 'Image' of a chord specified by some sort of drop-down?

This is the first time I've worked with Databases within an Android environment so I'm out of my comfort zone here; I'm aware I've only currently got one instance in my database for the 'C' chord I'm just looking guidance on how I'd tackle this if I had more than 1 item in there. Any dummy examples welcomed!

Here is my '**ChordImages.java**' file:

```
package com.finalyearproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ChordImages extends Activity {
 private MySQLiteHelper DbHelper;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.chordview);

      DbHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
      Chords chord_One = new Chords(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tuner_ic), "Chord C");

      DbHelper.open();
      DbHelper.insertCrdDetails(chord_One);
      DbHelper.close();
      chord_One = null;
      DbHelper.open();
      chord_One = DbHelper.retriveCrdDetails();
      DbHelper.close();

  TextView crdname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
  crdname.setText(chord_One.getName());

  ImageView crdphoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
  crdphoto.setImageBitmap(chord_One.getBitmap());
  }
}
```

My '**MySQLiteHelper.java**' file:

```
package com.finalyearproject;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MySQLiteHelper {

    public static final String CRD_ID = "id";
    public static final String CRD_NAME = "name";
    public static final String CRD_PHOTO = "photo";

    private DatabaseHelper mMySQLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ChordDB.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String CHORD_TABLE = "Chords";

    private static final String CREATE_CHORD_TABLE = "create table "
            + CHORD_TABLE + " (" + CRD_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + CRD_PHOTO
            + " blob not null, " + CRD_NAME + " text not null unique );";


    private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CHORD_TABLE);
  }

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CHORD_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
  }
 }

public void Reset() {

    mMySQLiteHelper.onUpgrade(this.mDb, 1, 1);
 }

public MySQLiteHelper(Context ctx) {

      mCtx = ctx;
      mMySQLiteHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
 }

public MySQLiteHelper open() throws SQLException {

    mDb = mMySQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
 }

public void close() {

    mMySQLiteHelper.close();
 }

public void insertCrdDetails(Chords chord) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(CRD_PHOTO, Utility.getBytes(chord.getBitmap()));
    cv.put(CRD_NAME, chord.getName());
    mDb.insert(CHORD_TABLE, null, cv);
 }

public Chords retriveCrdDetails() throws SQLException {

    Cursor cur = mDb.query(true, CHORD_TABLE, new String[] { CRD_PHOTO, CRD_NAME }, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            byte[] blob = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex(CRD_PHOTO));
            String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(CRD_NAME));
            cur.close();

            return new Chords(Utility.getPhoto(blob), name);
  }
        cur.close();
        return null;
 }
}
```

My '**Chords.java**' file:

```
package com.finalyearproject;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class Chords {

    private int id;
    private String chord;
    private Bitmap picture;

    public Chords(){}

    public Chords(Bitmap picture, String chord) {
        super();
        this.chord = chord;
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Chords [id=" + id + ", chord=" + chord + ", picture=" + picture + "]";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "Chord Name: " + chord;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return picture;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not actually sure what your question is. Are you getting errors / crashes? If so post the logcat. One thing I will say though - don't store images in a SQLite database - it may handle the BLOB type but it isn't efficient - save the images in your assets or raw directory and simply save the image names (URIs for example) in the database.

Comment: It's not so much an error or problem; I'm just new to the whole databases in android development area. I'm looking more guidance/advice if anything.

Comment: @Squonk I basically want some sort of drop-down menu or list of Guitar Chords on my ChordImages.java screen, and when I select (for example) the 'A Chord' it'll then display an Image of the A chord. Does this make sense, I could go into abit more detail if needs be.

Comment: Yeah...kind of difficult to answer in a concise form. Firstly you need to look at a cursor adapter approach - the most commonly used is `SimpleCursorAdapter`. If you do that, however, change the 'id' column to be `_id` (note the preceding underscore). Also, as I said, don't store your images as blobs in the DB just store a URI or filename. BTW, I'm a guitarist so I get the gist of what you're trying to do - a guitar "chord box" lookup app right?

Comment: @Squonk I'll look into that thanks, yeah well I have a guitar tuner and also working on this chord database as well. I have a Utility.java file that converts the .PNG images to a ByteArray before decoding them when they're called upon again

Comment: I meant to mention the "dropdown" widget in Android is the `Spinner` class (weird name I know). Good luck.